# How do I increase the resize margin on windows?

Tags: window-manager

It takes me about 5 tries to resize a window on my computer.

Is there a way to increase the resize margin on the edge of windows?

Comment: +1. The single pixel you get on the left and right borders in the default theme (and on the bottom now too, in Maverick's default) is a cruel joke.

Comment: This is still a relevant question. In Ubuntu 11.10, when not using Unity, my theme has borderless windows. It's supposed to have an invisible resize area outside the window, isn't it? Is there some way to enable this feature?

Comment: @bobince: seriously, how on earth could this ever have happened? it's the most intensely frustrating thing ever.

Comment: This nonsense is STILL a problem in 14.04. I don't know why the UI designers think a 1-pixel window border is acceptable. And don't even get me started on the lack of a real scroll bar.

Comment: This is possibly the most irritating thing about Ubuntu that I've ever found. Thanks for this question, you saved my mouse from being thrown at the wall. :)

Comment: Did you finally find a good theme that does the trick?

Comment: Between this *problem*, the scrollbar *problem* (yes they are PROBLEMS, not design opinions), the usability, stability, and performance sucking in general, and the UX design staff responding to bug reports with flippant, dismissive remarks (and even assuming their unfeasible rationales are so insightful as to be sufficient for any case I may present in advance)... I've ended up donating vast unnecessary time to issues in work life and personal life alike. This SERIOUS PROBLEM is effectively the "final straw" for me, and I've begun migrating all my clients away from Ubuntu like it's the plague.

Comment: Someone with an opposing bias to mine may offer such rationale as, "You can simply change the theme yourself!". I don't want to hear it unless you're willing to visit each of my users and give them a step-by-step "hand-holding" tutorial each and every time they spuriously encounter these type of problems... It has been *years* that numerous parties have been repeatedly reporting this *trivial to remedy* issue on account of the *devastating* effects it has on REAL-WORLD productivity, with not even a trace of hope in sight. (Does anyone visit this "real world" place anymore?)

Comment: Still a problem in 16.04.  Grab your torches and pitchforks and lets find this so-called "designer" who came up with this borderless crap.

Comment: Is it possible to resize the dragging area without increasing the window border size?

Comment: linux UX designers should work on Windows to learn a bit first... :)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it depends on the theme. Try a few out. What I frequently do instead is hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and middle-click (right-click in some environments) and drag to resize, which works anywhere on the window.

Note that many themes that seem to have a 1px border (or no border at all) actually do tend to have a generous invisible border just outside the window. You usually don't have to pinpoint a tiny window border to resize.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that you can use Alt+MiddleClick to resize. I only knew Alt+LeftClick to move.

Comment: Okay, but what about laptop owners with touchpads? How can I perform a middle-click-drag with a Synaptics touchpad?

Comment: @MiKy: Clicking both buttons at once simulates a middle-click on most touchpads. So alt + mash both -> drag should do the trick.

Comment: Nice trick, works well on the terminal windows for me, but not so well in when trying to resize emacs.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with internal borders, such as the style panel border, on LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: A nice trick, to be sure, yet there's no excuse for the "tweezy" interface along the window borders, especially given the high resolutions of today's displays. Really, it's just a single value somewhere in the code that needs to be edited.. but where??

Comment: Found the solution in Lubuntu 14.04:

sudo nano /usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/openbox-3/themerc

Edit the line: "border.width: 1" (try '3' or even '5'). Good luck.

Comment: For me it was Alt+RightClick which resized the windows, while Alt+MiddleClick sent them to back.

Comment: @stackount Same for me in 14.04, the answer should be updated.

Comment: I just can't upclick this enough! thanks so much

Comment: I wonder when someone from the Ubuntu developers will actually decide to fix this. For Heaven's sake, this issue is present for almost 6-7 years and this makes it even more frustrating. After all with the Unity interface isn't the OS supposed to be more touch/mouse-friendly? It is literally impossible to resize a window by using touch if you have the desktop install and the input device is just a touch screen unless you are a pixel sniper or lucky enough to hit the border's single pixel with your fat finger. :D

Comment: This doesn't work for resizing bookmarks sidebar, developer tools, or firebug in firefox.

Comment: It's <Meta>+<middle click> for me in Fedora

Comment: This is now <Meta>+<middle click> in Ubuntu by default as well.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 on an Intel desktop with a normal Pebble M355 mouse, and neither Alt+Right or Alt+Middle is working.  (no themes or tweaks, I'm vanilla)

Answer (score 49):

To modify Ambiance to have a wider margin, open `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml` and increase the values of the following properties:

```
<distance name="left_width" value="1"/>
<distance name="right_width" value="1"/>
<distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>
```

You may want to back up the original file before modifying, and/or make a duplicate of the entire theme.

Note that you can also resize windows by pressing Alt + Button2.

Comment: Why not package it by default in Ubuntu? There are drawbacks for this solution?

Comment: A major drawback would be that a wide visible border is usually aesthetically displeasing, as well as not being in line with other theme elements that have thin outlines. See http://blogs.fedoraproject.org/wp/mclasen/2010/10/09/getting-a-grip/ and http://blogs.gnome.org/metacity/2010/01/20/border-widths-under-user-control/ for better solutions for defaults.

Comment: Setting the bottom_height to 3 gives you a much larger area to grab without feeling you ruined the design of the theme.  Thanks for this answer! :)

Comment: It is a great approach, specially for netbooks when "smashing both buttons of a touchpad simultanesosuly *while* holding alt *and* perform a drag" is as cumbersome as trying to hit that thin border

Comment: I don't remotely feel like it's a major drawback. The difference is subjective, and could easily be preferable with wider borders. Meanwhile the annoyance and number of person-hours lost fiddling with this ridiculous issue on all levels is immense.

Comment: I have tested it working on Gnome (v12.04), but does not work on KDE, LXDE nor XFCE.

Comment: Works perfectly with Ubuntu 14.04 and the GNOME Metacity fallback!

Comment: use `$> mate-appearance-properties` to find out which theme you are actually running (thus, which .xml to open above), also for forth-and-back switching to refresh, this is helpful...

Comment: anyone too feeling a `find /usr/share/themes/ -name \*.xml -exec sed -i "s/<someStuffToDo>/<someStuffToDo>/g" {} \;` coming?

Comment: I found that for BlackMATE on Raspberry Pi Ubuntu MATE 16.04 that it was set in 

'/usr/share/themes/BlackMATE/metacity-1/metacity-theme-2.xml'

Answer (score 25):

There is also a default keyboard short-cut in gnome -- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> -- that is a 'resize window' function.

Comment: +1. Worth noting that this resizes the active window, not necessarily the one the mouse is over.

Comment: +1. Very nice approach! And you can also navigate to the desired border using the arrow keys. So `ALT+F8`, release, choose border with arrow keys, use arrows to resize, `ESC` to leave resize mode

Answer (score 16):

The GNOME desktop environment is designed to give priority to usability and simplicity over customizability. Hence, the width of the window border is something that is not easily changeable. In all practical considerations, Jacob's recommendation that you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+middle-click instead of dragging the window borders is likely to be the best solution for most users.

With that said, the size of the window border does vary between Metacity themes. As a first step, you might try picking a different theme from [GNOME-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=101).

If you're really determined to adjust just the window border without changing the rest of the theme, it is possible to modify existing themes. Here's a [reference to get you started](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/tutorials/metacity/metacity-themes.html).

Comment: Just a note: pressing and dragging with the middle mouse button is not always possible, like on some notebook touchpads (like mine)...

Comment: Excellent point. One workaround that should be fine for most people would be to check `/apps/metacity/general/resize_with_right_button` in `gconf-editor`. I've only seen a few graphics programs (Inkscape comes to mind) where this setting gets in the way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Alt-MiddleClick does not work on remote desktops.  The Alt-F8 does seem to work.

Comment: One cannot claim that usability is a priority if this fiddly, annoying, difficult to use default is being kept just to satisfy some subjective design aesthetic.

Comment: Simplicity is fine **BUT ONLY IF THE DEFAULTS WORK**.

Comment: How to achieve this in MATE (Gnome 3.0 based)?

Comment: `The GNOME desktop environment is designed to give priority to usability and simplicity`, It is pretty ironic that having a 1 pixel "hot" area for resizing is not user friendly at all.

Comment: Linux UX designers should work on Windows to learn a bit first...

Answer (score 7):

The thickness of the window border is set by the theme you are using.
So to make the window edges bigger try a different theme.

Comment: I want to make an addition: You don't have to give up your theme and pick a new one with altogether. You may change just the border. Go to System > Preferences > Appearance > Theme > Customize > Window Border and choose something with a thick border. (For example HumanLogin if you have a light colour background image, or SphereCrystal if you have a darker background, to obtain some contrast to see the borders more clearly).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this will be [fixed in Natty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/metacity/+bug/160311).

Comment: It wasn't. Or they reverted back to 1-pixel borders in Precise

Comment: This is still an issue in Trusty Tahr 14.04! You keep saying it's related to theme, but somebody explain me why all the default built-in themes except "Shiny" suffer from this incredible annoyance?? They look good, but I simply cannot choose them because I would go mad whenever trying to resize a window.

Comment: still an issue on 20.04   ....   Alt + F8  then arrow keys seems to work ( assuming you have F keys and arrow keys )

Answer (score 5):

(This is from my answer to [a duplicate question that was closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57028/how-do-i-increase-the-dragable-corner-size/). )

It depends on the theme used. You could change your theme, or edit the theme if you really wanted to, but an easier and more consistent way is to **hold down Alt and drag with the middle mouse button**. You can imagine it as slicing the window into a 3x3 grid, and clicking in any rectangle but the center one will allow you to drag the appropriate side or corner.

Note that **Alt + MiddleButton** is the default configuration. To change it (at least in **Compiz**):

1. Go to **System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager** if running classic **Gnome**, or search for **CompizConfig Settings Manager** in the Dash if running **Unity**.
2. Find the **Resize Window** plugin; it's under **Window Management**.
3. Open it and go to the **Bindings** tab if you aren't already there.

The last two settings are called **Initiate Window Resize**. One of them is the middle click option described above; the other is a similar keyboard binding that allows you to resize with the keyboard arrow keys (as well as the mouse without clicking).

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the title bar and select **R**esize from the popup menu.

Answer (score 1):

## Current Solution (2019) for Ubuntu-MATE 16.x, 18.x**

(possibly more, pls add to comments)

Yes, those borders are a pain, bordering on *–pun intended–* masochism...

[image]

### 1 create copy of a theme

Well, ClearLooks is (for some reason) not really a "full theme" to pick on the Theme tab, but rather a "Border Theme" under „customize..“ on the Window Border Tab:

[image]

Well, never mind, let's create a copy (use rsync or cp as you please):

(If you are fond of another "border theme" then duplicate that one accordingly. Look it up under customize theme-> Window Border what you are currently using.)

```
sudo rsync -vr /usr/share/themes/ClearlooksRe/* /usr/share/themes/ClearlooksReBIGGER
```

### 2 change border width in the xml File

```
sudo pluma /usr/share/themes/ClearlooksReBIGGER/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml
```

There are actually two places:

- under `<frame_geometry name="normal"...`
- under `<frame_geometry name="border"...`

For left, right and bottom I went for a rather generous 12px:

```
<distance name="left_width" value="12"/>    <!-- FRANK: was: 4 -->
<distance name="right_width" value="12"/>
<distance name="bottom_height" value="12"/>
```

3 pick the new Window Border theme and there you are

[image]

[Some background on metacity themes, if you care](https://blogs.gnome.org/metacity/2008/05/30/themes/).

Comment: What if the theme I'd like to start from ( _Daloa_ on Xubuntu 19.10) doesn't contain a `.../metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`?

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica (from the top of my head:) 1. prepare the above copy of this special theme (it is **not** a full theme anyway); 2. Pick the theme of your like (truly as a whole); 3. within your theme, navigate to customize…→ Windows Border. Pick aforementioned copy.

Comment: Well, there's _Settings_ → _Appearance_ → _Style_ and _Settings_ → _Window Manager_ → _Style_ → _Theme_ but none of them has a _customize..._ button.

Comment: I do not know about other Distros, but under Ubuntu Mate: Appearance: Theme Tab: pick the one you like. „Customize...“ (below, between „Save As“ and „Install“) → Window Border Tab → „ClearlooksReBIGGER“ (also works nice with light color themes, as I just figure out...)

Answer (score 0):

Alt+MiddleButton is the right way to resize windows; it's right are your hands, and you don't have to move the pointer to the window edges first.

However, I still find that the scroll overlay often gets in my hair.  So I went for a different approach and **disabled the overlays all together!**  Scroll still works, of course, and the nice orange scroll indicator is still present.  On Ubuntu 13.04, I did it like this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode 'overlay-touch'
```

You can revert it by doing:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode 'overlay-auto'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, to maximize the window the keyboard shortcut is ctrl+super+ up(on the keyboard) to minimize it is ctrl+super+down. To resize it is alt+ F8

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but IMO none of the answers really solved this particular question, they just added workarounds.

The actual answer to this is what's described in [this GitHub issue's comment](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/9341#issuecomment-636417578), which is to manually edit a setting that isn't exposed in the GUI. (No, the `Settings` > `Windows` > `Behavior` > `Window drag/resize threshold (Pixels)` entry doesn't fix this, contrary to what 99% of users would think.)

TL;DR The "real" solution to this is:

```
dconf write /org/cinnamon/muffin/draggable-border-width 20
```

where `20` represents "20 px". The default is 10 px. Note that `cinnamon` and/or `muffin` would be replaced with whichever environment you're using. Should be somewhat easy to decipher which pertains to your system since all the other Settings > Windows fields would be listed inside it (i.e. running `dconf list /org/env/windowsSettings/` would show the other Windows settings' fields).