# How to increase the Resize Margin with Compiz?

Tags: compiz, themes, window-manager, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase Resize Margin On Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/increase-resize-margin-on-windows)

Using the Ambience theme in combination with Compiz makes the resizing for many windows almost impossible without using the context menu and not nearly all windows provide a resize corner.

What's the best way to increase the window margin to a reasonable value?