# How can I make the draggable window border thicker, without changing the appearance?

Tags: gnome, window-manager

When you want to resize a window in gnome (as well as in other systems) you can click-and-hold at the window's border and than drag it. The problem is (and do correct me if I'm wrong here) that the draggable border is just a couple of pixels thick in gnome. That tends to be a little frustrating, and contributes to my wrist pains from using the mouse, as it requires very careful movement of the mouse.

**How can I change the thickness of the area I can click in order to resize a window?** I don't want to increase the appearance of the window border, I'm not talking about eye candy here. I want to fine tune this functionality where I can resize a window by dragging its border.

Is there a setting somewhere that will change this?

Comment: I admit I had not seen those questions. However, they both involve themes. I would like to change the functionality without affecting the appearance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the comments before I post my answer. You may totally forget about my answer if this post should be moved, deleted etc.

Comment: @Bruce: The solution of using `alt + middle-click` doesn't involve changing appearance. It's not strictly changing the border width, but it solves the same problem. In fact, it gives you a much wider area (the whole window) than you would get by changing the border width.

Comment: @Matthew: you need 2 hands free for that though...  ;)

Comment: @JanC: Or a spare button on your mouse you can rebind the shortcut to.

Comment: *Related:* [Increase Resize Margin On Windows](http://askubuntu.com/q/4109/1273)

Comment: @JanC: I agree that it isn't ideal, but at least it's a solution that doesn't involve changing appearance :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.

This is a three year old bug with no solution.

You either have to use a different theme or do as I have done and give up trying and use keys to resize windows.

Mini Howto:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to start resizing. 
Use arrow keys to resize.

Pressing Return will save the resize, escape will revert you back.

[The bug report is here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/metacity/+bug/160311) and has hundreds of comments on it and thirteen duplicate bug reports on launchpad alone.

Comment: You sort of can. See the two questions the Jorge linked above (particularly the second one).

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'll soon be logging into launchpad just to contribute and follow that bug.

Comment: @Bruce: Go ahead and follow it, but please don't comment on it unless you have a patch (see the warning at the top of the bug report). The developers are aware of it, but it's a technical issue and they asked not to be spammed about it any more.

Comment: As Matthew says, there are some answers. The other two questions on the same topic are merged on this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/increase-resize-margin-on-windows I'm deleting my answer because there are better answers on that thread.

Comment: After pressing `Alt+F8` you can also resize with the mouse (just move it).

Comment: @MatthewPirocchi Here it is 2015, and the bug is still in 15.10 Wily Werewolf. Maybe they need _more_ "spam" not less. A now eight-year-old bug should not be happening.

Comment: Also, in 15.10 Wily Werewolf - using the Greybird theme - Alt-F8 is for stick window, not resize. That can be changed with the Window Manager utility (I'm using Xubuntu).

Answer (score 24):

Change the following parameters in the appropriate Metacity XML file.

Ambiance's theme is located in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`

The folowing parameters change the width of the borders and consequently the width of the re-size area:

```
"<distance name="left_width" value="1"/>"
"<distance name="right_width" value="1"/>"
"<distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>"
```

By default they are set to "1", but I found that changing them to "4" doesn't change the appearance very drastically, but makes it very much easier to re-size using the mouse.

Comment: To reload the theme without logging out you can run the command: metacity-message reload-theme

Comment: If only I had root access to my computer...

Comment: thank you SO much @pgwulfing this is FINALLY the answer I've been looking for. The hotkeys don't work for me because I have an interactive ubuntu environment through a chrome tab and hotkeys are finicky at best with it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer: works on xubuntu 20.04
https://app.box.com/s/7gk3pwdn5onj5q5b9eowa2315qy8pcy3 (zip file) instructions:
https://mxlinux.org/wiki/xfce/changing-border-size-with-xfce4-window-manager/

Comment: Similar comment as https://askubuntu.com/questions/833950/size-of-grab-area-for-resizing-window-in-lubuntu/1351565#1351565 - please can the files be hosted on a public hosted platform?

Comment: Currently it has not been packaged and added to the MX repos or anywhere else. And I haven't figured out how to edit a current theme to include the changes made this way, someone who can come up with a modified theme is, of course free to try, and upload to a public forum. There seem to be instructions on that also at MXlinux forums under the same post/topic "changing-border-size-with-xfce4-window-manager/ "