# Resizing a window should be easier - increase boarder pixel count?

Tags: window, resize, usability

Currently its too difficult to resize a window by hovering cursor on window edge or corner until cursor changes to that double arrow pointer ... when I install Ubuntu 19.04 for people new to computers (very young or old) I see its hard for these people to perform this operation

Is there a config to help this ?  hold down key ? while doing above to encourage arrow pointer to appear

To see this yourself try using your opposite hand to resize a window

Best I have found (and admittedly klunky) is to ALT + right click and pick resize ... details at https://superuser.com/questions/436541/how-do-you-increase-the-resize-border-thickness-in-xubuntu-12-04/852347

Another approach [How can I make the draggable window border thicker, without changing the appearance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8498/how-can-i-make-the-draggable-window-border-thicker-without-changing-the-appeara)

ubuntu theme thick window boarder

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to test because my right handed mouse with palm and thumb molds won't fit in my left hand. I do appreciate it takes precise movements to grab window border when it is a small number of pixels. I imagine you can make the window border thicker though.

Comment: Have you looked at the available themes?  I'm sure some of them have fatter boarders.

Comment: Inncreasing "draggable-border-width" works for *some* applications: https://askubuntu.com/q/1155237/248158

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the resize margin on windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows)