# Ubuntu 18.04: does "draggable-border-width" work only for some applications?

Tags: resize, accessibility, mutter

After reading [Resizing a window should be easier - increase boarder pixel count?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1154887/248158) and the links cited there, I looked at what dconf-editor had. There is "/org/gnome/mutter/draggable-border-width" with this description:

> The amount of total draggable borders. If the theme's visible borders are not enough, invisible borders will be added to meet this value.

As shown in the image below, I've set the value to the maximum permissible `64` (marked in red).

[image: draggable-border-width setting]

I confirmed this setting in the terminal:

```
dkb@dkb:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "draggable-border-width "
org.gnome.mutter draggable-border-width 64
dkb@dkb:~$
```

However, the effective border width, as judged by the furthest I can place the mouse pointer (circled in black), doesn't change relative to the default which uses a value of `10` for windows of

- dconf-editor
- evince
- gedit
- nautilus
- settings
- sudoku
- totem movie player
- tweaks

But as the image below shows, with a gnome-terminal window, I can position the mouse pointer much further away from the visible border and still effect a resize. In other words, it looks like the setting of `64` is effective for gnome-terminal windows but not for the windows I listed above:

[image: draggable-border-width works for gnome-terminal]

---

Edit:

`64` also works for

- aisleriot
- featherpad
- firefox
- geany
- gwenview
- leafpad
- lxterminal
- mousepad
- shotwell
- uxterm
- xterm

Why is that?

---

I haven't changed any GNOME Shell settings. The GTK theme is Adwaita.