# Improve sensitivity of zoom pointer

Tags: 10.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase Resize Margin On Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/increase-resize-margin-on-windows)

I hope I can make myself clear, but I find myself struggling more often than not when I want to zoom any window in ubuntu 10.10. The pointer has to be positioned very nearly pixel-perfect before I get a zoom-pointer and get the ability to zoom the window.
This is especially true if you want to zoom from any of the bottom corners.

Is there some way so make this process a bit more forgiving? When I am in the vicinity of the corner i would like to be able to zoom.

So is there a setting to increase the margin, the area ... or other ways to somehow make my zooming life easier :)

Comment: You can also use Alt + the middle mouse button to resize a window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't, although you could change to a theme that has thicker window borders (such as Dust) in Preferences > Appearance. This is because the resize cursor is only visible when you are exactly on the border.

I feel your pain, as I find this irritating too, as do others:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/metacity/+bug/160311
http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/2571/

Answer (score 1):

On one of the [forums](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/2571/) @misterben posted, i read that

```
ALT + <middle-mouse-button>
```

will get you into zoom-mode immediately. So clicking in the corner is not necessary, just hold Alt and middle mouse button on the window to resize it. You dont have to be in the corner, just near a corner.  I find that awesome, because it is something i can do right away!

(i still hope it gets fixed someday)