# How do I resize my emacs22 window?

Tags: 10.04, emacs, window, resize

I tried searching for answers but can't find any.
I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and have emacs22 installed:

ii  emacs22                              22.2-0ubuntu9                                   The GNU Emacs editor (Emacs 22)
ii  emacs22-bin-common                   22.2-0ubuntu9                                   The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent file
ii  emacs22-common                       22.2-0ubuntu9                                   The GNU Emacs editor's common infrastructure
ii  emacsen-common                       1.4.19ubuntu1                                   Common facilities for all emacsen

I find that I cannot resize the outer frame (X window) of the emacs session.  When I move the mouse to the corner of the window, it doesn't change into the resize icon.... help!

Comment: Just to check that you're launching the x-windows version, rather that the terminal version, what does it say it you type: "ctrl-H V window-system"? Look at "Its value is ...".

Comment: window-system is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is x

Comment: I can't reproduce because emacs23 with 10.10 works fine -- do any of these work-arounds (such as using Alt-F8) work for you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/increase-resize-margin-on-windows

Comment: Not sure, but as a long-shot, what is: "ctrl-h v window-size-fixed"? It should be "nil". If you are not even getting a mouse-pointer change it sounds like X rather than emacs. You wouldn't possibly have something set in .Xdefaults would you?

Comment: Thanks, Alt-F8 allows me to change the width of the window at least.

Comment: window-size-fixed is nil and I don't have a .Xdefaults file (nor .Xresources)... guess I'll try upgrading to emacs23.

Comment: Try harder.  This is a problem with all applications in recent Ubuntu releases because the default theme only uses a single pixel thick border.  It might help if you tone down the mouse sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the emacs window geometry at startup ->

On you panel emacs icon or through the menu editor - set the command to run emacs like this -- emacs -geometry 135x42

See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92971/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-emacs-window) for other ways to do it!

Enjoy your bigger window!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a shortcut (e.g., Super-middlemouse) to resize windows.  Go to CompizConfig Settings Manager (or install it if you haven't) and open "Resize window".