# Why are window borders so hard to click in Ambiance?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, ambiance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I increase resize Margin on windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-resize-margin-on-windows)

In Lucid, I never had this problem. However, with Maverick Ambiance I've noticed that the window borders are extremely hard to grab, to resize the window. Why is this? And how would I go about fixing this while still using Ambiance?

Comment: Not exactly a dupe (it doesn't explain the why) but it has instructions on how to fix it.

Comment: The "why?" is simply because it was a design decision that was handed down to us. For more clarifications, look at OSX. The "how to fix" is on Jorge's link.

Comment: Well, the why is "it's a bug".  I don't think it was a conscience design decision to make borders hard to grab, just a consequence of the Ayatana team not thinking through the effects of this particular aesthetic change to the theme.  I've included an answer to that effect.  Up to you if you want to close it as dupe though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a reasonably well documented bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/light-themes/+bug/160311), introduced in Maverick (10.10), already fixed in Natty (11.04) and backported to Maverick via PPA.

The bug description has the details you need to fix this, but in summary, you can add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bratsche/+archive/gtk) here to apply the fix to Maverick.  NB : I haven't tested this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bratsche/gtk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk+2.0 - 2.22.0-0ubuntu2~bratsche1
```

(then remove the repository, perhaps using Synaptic, or the next update you do will get all of his additional packages)

Or if you don't mind the aesthetic, you can simply edit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml.

Set the following values in frame_geometry_normal as desired:

```
    <distance name="left_width" value="3"/>
    <distance name="right_width" value="3"/>
    <distance name="bottom_height" value="3"/>
```

Looks pretty ugly though!