# how do i increase the dragable corner size?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I increase the resize margin on windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows)

I have found that in 10.10 and 10.04 that the draggable corner for windows ( where it allows you to resize them ) is far too small.  Is there someway to make it turn into the resize function in a larger area?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the theme used. You could change your theme, or edit the theme if you really wanted to, but an easier and more consistent way is to **hold down Alt and drag with the middle mouse button**. You can imagine it as slicing the window into a 3x3 grid, and clicking in any rectangle but the center one will allow you to drag the appropriate side or corner.

Note that **Alt + MiddleButton** is the default configuration. To change it (at least in **Compiz**):

1. Go to **System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager** if running classic **Gnome**, or search for **CompizConfig Settings Manager** in the Dash if running **Unity**.
2. Find the **Resize Window** plugin; it's under **Window Management**.
3. Open it and go to the **Bindings** tab if you aren't already there.

The last two settings are called **Initiate Window Resize**. One of them is the middle click option described above; the other is a similar keyboard binding that allows you to resize with the keyboard arrow keys (as well as the mouse without clicking).