# Resize/Move edge too narrow on windows

Tags: window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I increase the resize margin on windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows)

When hovering near the edge of a window you get an option to resize them.

However that edge is too narrow when I'm using trackpoint or touchpad, making it difficult to hit the 'sweet spot'

Is there a way I can increase the width (respectively height) of the 'hot-zone' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like the keyboard shortcut as the easiest way to resize the window and totally avoid trying to grab the edge of the window!  Try Alt-F8 then use either the keyboard arrow keys or your mouse/touchpad to resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt open your terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar-0.1-0
```

Then restart.
That would replace the new overlay scrollbars for the classic ones (that are more "handly")

If you want the new scrollbar back, open a terminal and run this:

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar-0.1-0
```

Hope it helps (:

Comment: This method works, but stops some capabilites. For example: the X11VNC's clients lose the ability to (remotely) move or resize windows.