# Adjust window resize sensitivity

Tags: 14.10, window-manager, mate

(Sorry for bad title)

I'm using Mate and I have this problem when if I want to resize a window, the mouse icon doesn't switch to "resize mode" unless I am literally on the border of the window. I pretty much need to get it exactly on the pixel to be able to resize, and it is incredibly annoying. Anyone know how to fix this, or where I can find this in the source code so I can play with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Annoying, old bug, also [mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/1012464/mate-how-to-increase-window-resizing-area) [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows). Changing your current theme (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1027320)) would be the most perfect option. The easiest one, withou changes, is probably:

1. be near the window border (in a generous 30-40 pixel sense)
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Mousebutton</kbd>