# How do I change the click target area for the corner box expand to expand a window in Unity Desktop?

Tags: unity, mouse, gui, window

When trying to adjust the size of a GUI window (such as my terminal editor window) I have to be **exactly** on the bottom right hand corner before the window-adjust icon appears.

The target area is so narrow that it's almost impossible to hit.  It's like a game of cat and mouse (no pun intended).

I'm aware that a window can be adjusted by clicking the middle mouse button whilst hold the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key down, but I prefer the traditional way.

Sorry I don't have the vocabulary to describe this in UX terms, but is there a way to make this 'work' correctly- it's just awful?

Comment: Already explained: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows