# How to increase resize margins for windows in Ambiance theme for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, themes

Here [How do I increase the resize margin on windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows) it says to edit in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml` the properties

```
<distance name="left_width" value="1"/>
<distance name="right_width" value="1"/>
<distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>
```

Well, there are three frames with those properties, and the default values are:

```
<frame_geometry name="frame_geometry_normal" title_scale="medium" rounded_top_left="true" rounded_top_right="true" rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="1"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="1"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="1"/>
</frame_geometry>

<frame_geometry name="geometry_maximized" rounded_top_left="false" rounded_top_right="false" rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="0"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="0"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="0"/>
</frame_geometry>

<frame_geometry name="border" has_title="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="3"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="3"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="3"/>
</frame_geometry>
```

I have already altered all three to ridiculous values to no visible effect:

```
<frame_geometry name="frame_geometry_normal" title_scale="medium" rounded_top_left="true" rounded_top_right="true" rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="100"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="100"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="100"/>
</frame_geometry>

<frame_geometry name="geometry_maximized" rounded_top_left="false" rounded_top_right="false" rounded_bottom_left="false" rounded_bottom_right="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="100"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="100"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="100"/>
</frame_geometry>

<frame_geometry name="border" has_title="false">
  <distance name="left_width" value="200"/>
  <distance name="right_width" value="200"/>
  <distance name="bottom_height" value="200"/>
</frame_geometry>
```

and have rebooted between changes.

What am I missing? (and how to effect changes without rebooting?)

Comment: Please tell what session and/or what window manager is used. There might be `metacity-theme-2.xml` or `metacity-theme-3.xml` files. Which file is used depends on window manager.

Comment: @muktupavels

`$     wmctrl -m`

**Name: Compiz**

Is this what you asked for? 
 
Also `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance$ ls`  
**gtk-2.0  gtk-3.0  index.theme  metacity-1  unity**

Comment: If you use default Ubuntu session - Unity then it does not use Metacity theme. Also by default resize margins are 10px big, why do you want to change that? Or maybe you have problem with few windows?

Comment: @muktupavels bc I've got a disability and those 10pixels still feel hard to click on. What do you suggest? Any way to change the default theme? Or "just select Metacity to use" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css` file. Find `-UnityDecoration-input-extents` line and change `10px` to something larger.

If you have gtk-3.20 folder then you need to edit `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/apps/unity.css` file. In case you update your ubuntu version.