# How do I increase the width of the resizing area in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes, window, window-management

It is very hard to resize a window in Ubuntu 20.04. The resizing UI widget has to be precisely placed (< 5 pixels).

[image: <5 pixels width]

The answer to [How do I increase the resize margin on windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows) does not work for 20.04.

How do I increase the resize margin in 20.04?

Answer (score 1):

Various *workarounds* posted to the [other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/4109/480481) you mentioned are still usable on Ubuntu 20.04 though.

For example, the workaround mentioned in the [top scoring and the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/4112/480481) still works in a sense:

[image]

The only difference is that on Ubuntu 20.04 the default window action key is <kbd>Super</kbd> (usually the key with the Windows logo) *instead of* <kbd>Alt</kbd>. So you can resize windows by pressing and holding down <kbd>Super</kbd> and then middle mouse click and drag.

You can also change your window action key to <kbd>Alt</kbd> using (GNOME) Tweaks. Launch Tweaks and change the key for the '*Window Action Key*' option in the '*Windows*' section.

---

Similarly, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> trick mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23600/480481) also works fine on Ubuntu 20.04 and so does the right-clicking on the title bar and selecting the '**Resize**' from the context-menu trick as mentioned in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/755466/480481).

Comment: Hot keys aren't what I'm looking for. . I do not want to compell users to use Hot keys. I want to change the margins to  have an acceptable UX expectations.

Comment: You linked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4109/how-do-i-increase-the-resize-margin-on-windows) and said "*The answer* ... does not work for 20.04." without actually mentioning any *specific* answer. I just pointed out that various *workarounds* posted as answers to the that question (including the top answer) are still valid in 20.04 (with a slight change perhaps), that's about it. :)

Comment: Your right - It's still valid if you want to avoid or can not change the actual width.. My original question referenced the second answer specifically which was to modify an theme xml file. This worked fine in 19.04 My question however was deemed needing 'clarity' so I dropped it and added a picture.  No malice  intended.